# SVN: move a directory up one level

Tags: svn

Suppose you have a directory

```
A/A/
```

containing a project. The duplicated  Folder name came to be by accident and should be (re)moved - i.e. the project should sit in `A/` directly.

Clearly

```
svn mv A/A/ .
```

does not work, it will say something like

> svn: E150002: Path '..../A' already exists

The solution that I have found so far is

```
svn mv A/A/* A/
```

However, this will not move all files - some are ignored.
For instance folders starting with a dot (.idea).

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to delete a directory called A and put another directory of the same name to replace it *before the initial directory is actually deleted*. obviously this is not going to work!

I would move and rename the subdir, and then rename it again after committing to delete the first one.

Its possible committing the initial delete and then moving the now-hidden subdir might work (you'll have to move URL to URL not using the working copy), but it seems too much of a trick to use for me when something simple is easier to do.

Comment: So if I got you right, both solutions involve more than a single commit, right?

Comment: I think so - if they were different names, it'd be another matter.